# Android Studio : eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android, debugging

Trying to debug using emulator an android application Im trying to code.

I get this error code

```
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

What does it mean when that error appears how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Swap to use GenyMotion emulator. It has better OpenGL support.

Comment: Please copy the entire error message and the relevant code and paste it to your post. It's kind of hard to read on here, and imgur will expire at some point.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: @Simon I'm getting the same error even with the GenyMotion devices, W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with OpenGL. I've seen it before, most commonly with using GenyMotion and then sleeping/resuming my computer. 
Restarting the emulator and launching your app again should fix it.

Comment: I don't use GenyMotion, and I attempted to do both of those things (restart computer and launch app again) didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Ben Pearson Hi slightly off topic, but is thre a way to use google services on genymotion?

Comment: @jQwierdy Afraid on Genymotion is the only place I have seen it, so not sure what else to suggest. You could try restarting your device instead of your computer.

Comment: Discussion of the emulator graphics acceleration setting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented

Answer (score 1):

When creating your emulator, try selecting "Use Host GPU" within the settings.

And if you try testing on a real device you likely, should face the same problem

Comment: Actually, the suggestion is NOT to chose "Use Host GPU". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented