# Issues with expanding a TextView with animation and maxLines?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to expand a TextView with animation and as per several SO posts and tutorials I have gotten what I think should work. The following code does set the ellipsize property based on whether the TextView is expanded or not and changes the button image as well.

It does not actually expand the text view though, is it something in my layout that is not letting it push the content below the text view down?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="445dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerMainCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/swipecard_shadow"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainCardLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="430dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="top">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_jobTitle"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="General Labourer"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_companyName"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="ABC Company"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/laborswipe_lightgray"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardHeaderLabels"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_experienceReqHeader"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_briefcase"
                    android:text="Experience"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_locationLabel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_location"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_payRateLabel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_payrate"
                    android:text="Payment (hr)"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardHeaderData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_experienceReq"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#505353"
                    tools:text="3-5 years"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#505353"
                    tools:text="Vancouver"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_payRate"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#505353"
                    tools:text="$25"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTopDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:background="@color/laborswipe_lightgray"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_JobDesc"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:text="aasdf
                 a 
                 a 
                 a 
                 a 
                 "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_descExpand"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/arrow_expand"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/descriptionBottomDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:background="@color/laborswipe_lightgray"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardFooterLabels"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_dateRangeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_date"
                    android:text="Start - End"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_durationLabel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_clock"
                    android:text="Paid Hours"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_requirementsLabel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#f29d00"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_hardhat"
                    android:text="Requirements"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

onClickListener:

```
holder.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isExpanded) {
                    expand.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.arrow_expand, 0, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //desc.setMaxLines(3);
                    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                            desc,
                            "maxLines",
                            3);
                    animation.setDuration(200);
                    animation.start();

                    desc.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                    isExpanded = false;
                } else {
                    expand.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.arrow_collapse, 0, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //desc.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                            desc,
                            "maxLines",
                            25);
                    animation.setDuration(200);
                    animation.start();

                    desc.setEllipsize(null);
                    isExpanded = true;
                }

            }
        });
```

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

Logcat of clicking expans:

```
07-17 13:29:15.322 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 13:29:15.322 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3119160, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-17 13:29:17.282 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2b16770
```

Logcat of collapsing:

```
07-17 13:30:18.614 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 13:30:18.614 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa32be800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-17 13:30:20.543 20881-20907/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7daa70
```

Comment: Are there any `log errors` ? post them if any.

Comment: I've edited the OP with the logcat messages I see when I try to expand and collapse the textview.

Comment: Seems it is an opengl error, Try this { http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085777/android-studio-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented } thread and see if it helps you out.

Comment: I just tried the suggestions in that thread and no luck. I've also tried it on an actual device and same issue, the text field does not expand :(. I tried not using the animation and just setting maxLines but that did not work either unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you getting the same `logcat errors` even when you are not using animation ?

Comment: Yes, same logcat errors.

Comment: I followed this SO post to use the animation but I don't think the animation is causing this. Maybe my layout does not allow the textview to expand? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082322/animate-maxlines-and-ellipsize/17131297

Comment: Possibly, but you can also try to use this ExpandableLayout library { https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout } in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will take a look at that and try to implement it.

Comment: Alright, I hope you find it helpful